# NetBeans debugging of Python (GAE)

Tags: python, debugging, google-app-engine, netbeans

dev_appserver works normal when run it. But if i try o debug, i found an error caused by

```
     __file__
```

that is changed on jpydaemon.py. Has anyone successfully debugged apps on NetBeans?

Answer (score 1):

Nope but I'm interested in setting this up. You have to attach the netbeans debugger to the port somehow. This may help you: here's an example I was reading about for java: http://blogs.oracle.com/leonfan/entry/netbeans_development_series_for_google

Quoted what I found pertinent to your question dynback
"How to debug application for Google App Engine

Since we already map 'test' action to 'debug', we should right click on project and choose 'test' to do debug'. When system is running and listenning on Java remote debug port 5005, attach debugger under menu 'Debug':"

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the port in your debug settings is not in use.

I am assuming you have the python plugin in stalled for Netbeans.

Go to your settings and select python and then the Debugger tab.
The debugger port is set there.

Check your in use ports (In Windows open a command prompt and run the NetStat command)

If the port configured in the debugger tab is in use then select a port that is not in use and try again.

The default port appears to be 29100 but when I first installed the python plugin that was not the setting I saw there.
When I changed it back to the default which was not in use it worked.
I hope that helps.